# Notepad++ unable to fetch data from POSTMAN using $_POST method

Tags: php, postman

Is there any reason why my notepad++ PHP unable to read/fetch data from POSTMAN using $_POST method?

```
<?php

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){



    if(isset($_POST['ClassroomID'])){

        $ClassroomID = $_POST['ClassroomID'];

        echo $ClassroomID;

    }

    $response['error'] = "0";
    $response['message'] = "Connected to server";

}else{

    $response['error'] = "1";
    $response['message'] = "Unable to connect to server, Please try again.";

}

echo json_encode($response); 


 ?>
```

As you can see, I added key(ClassroomID) and Value(101) in this picture[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7zFz.png) that will be pass to notepad++ PHP, where it should display back the value but somehow it didn't. Anyone know of what reason makes notepad++ unable to display the data?.

Comment: What this have to do with Notepad++?

Comment: because I'm using notepad++ as a platform to write PHP, so I thought maybe notepad++ related too in this discussion. Sorry. @Toto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're passing `params`.

There is difference between HTTP POST and GET, `params` used when you try to send `GET` request.

You need to use `form-data` instead of `params` when making `POST` request using POSTMAN. You can find form-data in tab `Body`. [image]

Comment: It works!. Thank you so much for answering my question.